# Why constructor of base class-2 is not called?

Tags: c++

In the following code. Why constructor of base2 class is not called ? any help appreciated.

I tried to link with "Diamond Problem" but still not clear.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base {
public:
     base(){print1();};

     ~base(){std::cout << "Destructor of base1" << std::endl;};

     void print1(void) const
     {
         std::cout << "From print1 function" << std::endl;
     }
};

class base2:public base {
public:
     base2(){print1();};

     ~base2(){std::cout << "Destructor of base2" << std::endl;};

     void print1(void) const
     {
         std::cout << "From print2 function" << std::endl;
     }
};

class test: virtual public base2, public base {
    int a;
public:
    int b;
    test(){b = 0; print();};

    ~test(){ std::cout << "Destructor of test" << std::endl;};

     void print(void) const
     {
         //print1();
         //a++;
         std::cout << "From print function" << std::endl;
     }
};

int main()
{
    const test *t1 = new test();
  //  t1->print();
    delete t1;
    //cout<<"Hello World: " << t1->b;

    return 0;
}
```

From print1 function
From print function
Destructor of test
Destructor of base1
Destructor of base2
Destructor of base1

Comment: [Not reproducible](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb3ff746aa2b7e9f). Did you miss part of the output and got confused?

Comment: Destructor is fine. I want to know why "From print2 function" print is not in output from base2 class constructor.

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and add the output you expect. Also tell us what platform/compiler/OS you use.

Comment: What's your compiler? What version? What platform?

Comment: Virtual inheritance is weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, Compiler issue! If I tried in online compiler than constructor of base2 class not called and If I tried to run same in my local environment using g++ compiler than work fine. get output as expected. Thanks StoryTeller.

Comment: What online compiler?

Comment: onlinegdb .....

Comment: @GajjarHardik could not reproduce on gdbonline either: https://onlinegdb.com/SkgkK2NGV. Could you provide the link?

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/rkd50hEfE